# Javascript: "Object reference chain is too long error"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to click all links that have "See More" for the text like so:

```
var iterator = document.evaluate("//a[contains(text(), 'See More')]", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

// Wrapped in a try to avoid document object modified error
try { var x = iterator.iterateNext();
  while(x) { x.click(); x = iterator.iterateNext(); }
}
catch(e) {}
```

When I run the code, I get an "Object reference chain is too long error" after the first click. Any ideas how to fix?

**UPDATE**

The following code worked without error. The problem is the class name was not always consistent so I'm trying to get something more robust by using something like the code above.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("NameOfClass"); [...x].forEach(function(item) { item.click(); });
```

Comment: What happens if clicked on `a`, is there any click handler.

Comment: Yes, it reveals more text on the page.

Comment: [This works](http://jsbin.com/tapemeqako/edit?html,js,console,output), so problem is probably in your click handler.

Comment: Not so sure. See my update.

Comment: Show your click handler.

Comment: But why would the click event work for the getElementsByClassName and not for the xpath selector? They must be different kinds objects.

Comment: OK, nevermind. I just learned about the document.querySelectorAll function which allows me to select my element with css syntax. This gives me the sufficient precision to select the element I'm interested in finding. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I don't feel like the update appropriately addressed the original question since the solution was to reference the object differently <?>... I'm having this problem using `document.getElementById` and the node is at the top of my document but I still get the "reference chain is too long" error.